# The tank in the figure is accelerating upwards($+y$ direction) at a rate of $2.94 \ \text{m/$s^2$}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

"The tank in the figure is accelerating upwards($+y$ direction) at a rate of $2.94 \ \text{m/$s^2$}$. The pressure $P_1$ above the liquid in the tank is $1.41 \ \text{psig}$. The tube end is open to atmospheric pressure. The liquid has a density of $1570 \ \text{kg/$m^3$}$. What is $\Delta H$ in cm during the acceleration?" Not sure how to make use of the acceleration rate.

I found g* to find the pressure gradient, then integrated the pressure to find the pressure as a function of $y$ and I don't know what to do from there.

my work looks like: 9721.608 Pa - 101325 Pa = (1570 kg/m^3)((9.8m/s^2) + (2.94m/s^2)) delta H
not sure if my unit conversions are the issue but the answer is suppose to be 48.57cm with a margin of 1.4571.

[image]

Comment: What is "psig" and g* supposed to be?

Comment: psig is gauge pressure, and g* is the resultant vector of the acceleration vector and gravity vector.

Comment: Hello! You can find a basic MathJax/LaTeX tutorial for displaying formulas [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta P = \rho$ g* $\Delta H$.  Since the tank is accelerating upwards, $g*$ is the sum of $g$ plus the upwards acceleration.  Also, $\Delta P = P_1 - P_{atm}$, and since the liquid is incompressible, its density will remain constant under acceleration.  This leaves $\Delta H$ as your only unknown.

Comment: I tried solving the equation like that but got the answer wrong.

Comment: @emmilyy10 Edit your post with your attempted solution, so that we can see what you've done.

Comment: @Petersmith done

Comment: @emmilyy10, your $\Delta P$ should be the pressure measured in psig, because that is how much above atmospheric pressure your system is operating at.  In other words, $\Delta P = 9722 Pa$ ... you should NOT subtract atmospheric pressure from this value.

Comment: @DavidWhite thank you so much!